# No way to resolve conflict between "System.Xml

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio-2015, mono, xamarin.forms

I have this error when i do "Rebuild" on my Android Project using Xamarin Forms in Visual Studio 2015. When i Build the project I have no errors, then I try to Deploy and i only have deploy failed error so I try to Rebuild and I have errors like the image attached. It seems a reference error of Mono DLLs but because I don't do anything of strange, I only create a new cross platform pcl project, i think there's some requirements missing of a bug in some template of Visual Studio....[image] Here the folder of MonoAndroid maybe something missing? [image: Here the folder of MonoAndroid maybe something missing?]

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the rebuild output, it looks like your rebuild has succeeded.
Therefore Deployment should not give any issues.
Try setting the Solution Platform to x86 or ARM and try deploying the solution again.

To try to resolve the `System.Xml` issue,
Go to Nuget Package manager for the App5.Droid project and update all `System.Xml` from there to the latest version.
Also make sure that all the projects in your Solution use the same version of `System.Xml`

OR

You can edit the `project.json` file in the project folder with text editor and hard code the version number of `System.Xml` entry

Comment: Tried to set x86 but no difference. About Nuget Package manager, there's no System.xml package to update.

Comment: Try the second method by editing project.json file and manually entering the version number

Comment: wich version number i have to use?

Comment: Use 4.0.0.0 if you have used all newer API's otherwise use the older one.
However I would advice you to use 4.0.0.0 and port all deprecated API's to the newer API's